Auto-Formatting when saving a file and running a file
Whenever I save my file, one specific line of code is auto-indented. Whenever I run my file this line of code is also auto-indented. The video shows this. The weird thing is that basically the same code on line 20 is not auto formatted.
https://youtu.be/DuxrF6TD3QI?si=CSNKUqDgg-nOM_K1
I tried to go into my settings and 'Search for Format On Save' and toggle it off to disable auto-formatting but it was already disabled. Also, whenever I go to a window like chrome or messages or click anything outside of vscode, it also auto formats like in the video. I've never had this problem before but I noticed that it only occurs in the Dev Container.
https://youtu.be/DuxrF6TD3QI?si=CSNKUqDgg-nOM_K1
This the json file for the dev container:
{
    "name": "comp110-24s-003",
    "image": "krisjordan/trailhead:0.2.0",
    "workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/workspace,type=bind,consistency=cached",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
    "remoteUser": "vscode",
    "forwardPorts": [
        1110
    ],
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "ms-python.python",
                "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
                "ms-python.black-formatter",
                "ms-python.flake8",
                "ms-toolsai.jupyter"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "files.autoSave": "onWindowChange",
                "editor.formatOnSave": true,
                "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",
                "[python]": {
                    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
                    "editor.formatOnSave": true
                },
                "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
                "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
                "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
                "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
                    "reportMissingParameterType": "error",
                    "reportGeneralTypeIssues": "error",
                    "reportDeprecated": "error",
                    "reportImportCycles": "error"
                },
                "files.exclude": {
                    "**/.git": true,
                    "**/.svn": true,
                    "**/.hg": true,
                    "**/CVS": true,
                    "**/.DS_Store": true,
                    "**/Thumbs.db": true,
                    "**/__pycache__": true,
                    "**/.pytest_cache": true,
                    "**/.mypy_cache": true,
                    "**/.flake8": true,
                    "**/pyrightconfig.json": true,
                    "**/.gitignore": true,
                    "**/.vscode": true,
                    "**/tools": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "runArgs": [
        "--name",
        "comp110-24s-003"
    ]
}


what happens if you set editor.formatOnSave in your JSON file to false?
Like this:
"[python]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
      "editor.formatOnSave": false
 },


I tried it and saved it. When I open the Dev container it still has the same problem.

Not only python, FormatOnSave for vscode Settings also needs to be turned off. Open Settings and search for FormatOnSave and uncheck it.
